# Lotus Domino web: How to copy some of field values in current document, save it to a new document and redirect the browser to open the new document

Tags: lotus-domino

I need help in Lotus Domino Web. In the view, Last Name is clickable. When I click on one document (Last Name = e.g, Doe), the document will open and there would be a button named "Add Guest".

Once the Add Guest button was clicked, some of the field values in current document must be copied (Date Created, Time Created, Status), copied document must be saved, and copied document MUST open using PRINT (?EditDocument) so I can add some additional details in the document.

Note that this is Web, not Client.

[Screen shot of view with last name, and current document with Add Guest button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx1xp.png)

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  During the WebQuerySave event for the first document, you can get the values from the session.DocumentContext, create a new document in the back end, save it and then redirect to it.

Comment: What Duston just said + what seems to be the problem exactly ?

Comment: Additionally, do you really want to do a round-trip to the server ? Do you really have to use "print" ? It seems to me that this sort of things would be better taken care of by client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Duston and @ericviala, I was able to save the current document as new document and copied some of the field values from the current document. How do I redirect the page after saving the new document to itself and opening it to edit mode without the use of PRINT?

Comment: I've edited your question to emphasize that you are asking how to redirect. The way it was written, it seemed that you were asking about printing the document!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have written a WebQuerySave agent using LotusScript, the DocumentContext is the variable 'context' and the copied document is the variable 'newdoc'.

After you save the new document...

```
print "[http://" + context.Server_Name(0) + "/" + newdoc.ParentDatabase.Filepath + "/0/" + newdoc.UniversalID + "?EditDocument]"
```

This must be the only print statement that executes in your agent.

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for replying. I am not using the web querysave agent. I'm using an agent being called in a button. 

Now after the agent was processed and the new document was saved, I'm having a dillema in opening the created document in edit mode. Below code is a snippet from the button Javascript. add.new click contains the agent for saving.

     `myForm.addnew.click();`
     `window.open(myForm.AddGuestURL.value)`

With this code I'm getting: HTTP Web Server: Corrupt Data Exception

Comment: You've probably got a timing problem. The script doesn't wait after the call to click(). It calls window.open(), but the action on the server is not complete yet, so you have corrupt data. The right way to do this is with a submit that runs a WebQuerySave agent. The agent won't return until the copy is complete, so you won't have this problem. You can still get it to open a new window, but the trick is that the WQS agent prints a redirect to the same document, not to the copy. The agent sets a hidden field value to newdoc.UniversalID, and the onload event detects this and opens the new window.